# Webpack и Asp.NET MVC 5. Зависает сборка приложения в Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webpack, iis, iis-express

Реализован проект на Asp.Net MVC 5. К проекту был добавлен webpack.

Скрипты из `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode development --progress",
    "build::prod": "webpack --mode production --env.production --progress",
    "dev::watch": "webpack --mode development --verbose --watch",
    "dev": "webpack --mode development --verbose --watch",
  }
```

Также перед сборкой проекта отрабатывает следующий скрипт:

```sh
if '$(Configuration)'=='Release' (
    npm run build::prod
) else (
    npm run dev # или npm run dev::watch
)
```

Если запускать сборку решения с использованием пре-билд скрипта `npm run dev::watch`, то сборка решения зависает. Webpack сообщает о том, что все js-файлы скомпилированы, но сборка решения не продвигается.
Если убрать флаг `--watch`, то сборка решения идет в штатном режиме.

1) Как правильно использовать `webpack` с проектами Asp.Net MVC 5 и с использованием `--watch`?

2) Есть ли какие-нибудь практики по использованию HMR в проектах Asp.Net MVC 5? Существует ли какой-нибудь аналог `UseWebpackDevMiddleware()` из .Net Core?

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: я не спец конечно, но мне кажется, что вот эта команда `--watch` инструктирует ваш webpack вместо завершения работы, оставатсья запущенным и следить за изменениями файлов. То есть в скрипте сборки эта команда явно лишняя.

Comment: @tym32167, все верно. может быть знаете, как тогда использовать HMR и/или просто отслеживание файлов в webpack на данной платформе?

Comment: не, я бы рад помочь но ничего не смыслю в webpack

Answer (score 0):

Вышли из ситуации следующим образом.

Добавили `webpack-dev-server`. Теперь, кроме запуска самого приложения, рядом запускаем `webpack-dev-server`. Команда в npm: `webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --port 9000`.

Настройки devServer, которые мы используем:

```js
devServer: {
   contentBase: ".",
   host: "localhost",
   hot: true
}
```

В `Web.config` добавили следующие переменные:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="UseWebpackDevServer" value="true" />
    <add key="WebpackDevServerRoot" value="http://localhost:9000" />
</appSettings>
```

Также создали класс с настройками:

```cs
public static class Settings
{
    public static bool UseWebpackDevServer => "true".Equals(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UseWebpackDevServer"], StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    public static string WebpackDevServerRoot => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebpackDevServerRoot"];
}
```

Добавили в Layout.cshtml следующее условие:

```cs
@if (Settings.UseWebpackDevServer)
{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@(Settings.WebpackDevServerRoot)/main.min.js"></script>
}
else
{
    <script src="~/Scripts/main.min.js"></script>
}
```

Заработало вместе с Hot Module Replacement. Оригинал статьи [здесь](https://www.mattburkedev.com/integrate-webpack-and-asp-dot-net-mvc-slash-webapi/).